# Closures in For Loops With Onclick Assignment

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick, closures

I'm trying to have a navBar that generates automatically by looping through an array of "Page" objects. Unfortunately, I seem to be falling into the loops/closure trap. I have read several threads related to this and in some cases have copy and pasted solution code and passed in my own variables but I'm struggling to make it assign onclicks correctly.

I know I'm close. In the below code are two options that I have tried.

Am I getting something wrong with the paremeter in parenthesis in the self-calling function? - the ()(divId)? I don't really understand this part.

Could I also be struggling because this is being done as an object method?

Any help much appreciated but go easy on me, I'm learning all this in my spare time! ;)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mcgettrm/fs0mtz6n/**

```
var navBar = {
display: function(){
    for(i=0;i<pages.length;i++){
        document.getElementById('navBar').innerHTML += pages[i].token;
        var divId = pages[i].unique;

// code works fine up to here.
// option one(below): when navBar.display() is called the following code only adds
// the onclick to the final navbar link

        document.getElementById(divId).onclick=(function(divId) { 
                return function() { 
                alert(divId);
            }; 
        })(divId);

//option two(below): when navBar.display() is called the following code logs 
// the individual div id's correctly. But, it does it without being clicked. Then, 
// only the last item in the loop is clickable.

        (function(divId){
                document.getElementById(divId).onclick= function(){
                    console.log(divId);
                }
            }
        )(divId);
    }
}
```

};

Comment: Interesting problem, I've tried various variations of IIFE and every time only the last element gets assigned the onclick handler.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your comment - I spent hours working on this. It's actually really helpful just to know that it's not just me. Sometimes when you're covering new ground it can be hard to know if you're simply being silly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working here - https://jsfiddle.net/pqu9kr85/ it doesn't seem to have been to do with the binding of `i` more that you needed to build up the navigation html first, making sure it was in the DOM before binding the event. I put two separate loops, one to generate the nav, the second to bind the events. Also updated the `page.display()` to use `this` as that will have been affected by the value of `i`.